# Grub rescue issue

Tags: grub2, usb, windows

I used my laptop (which has Windows 7 installed on the hard drive) to install Ubuntu 12.04 from a DVD to a USB stick.  The operation said it completed but the USB stick would not boot. Only got a cursor in the upper left corner of the display.  I rebooted the laptop without the DVD and stick and now is comes up with

```
error: no such device: 47ce9a0d-797f-47c2-88f8-1c5a4ac1b14d
```

How can I get back to my os on the hard drive?

The USB stick and dvd have been removed.  It appears that the install from dvd to usb modified the disk drive by installing grub on it and now the system is trying to find a bootable stick on power up. Don't know how to remove the grub from it so I can boot from Windows.

Comment: Have you just removed the USB?

Comment: your question was not clear,please edit it.